# Sorting files in a list

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of files

```
files = ['s1.txt', 'ai1.txt', 's2.txt', 'ai3.txt']
```

and I need to sort them into sub-lists based off of their number so that

```
files = [['s1.txt', 'ai1.txt'], ['s2.txt'], ['ai3.txt']]
```

I could write a bunch of loops, however I am wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Is the list of files already sorted by number, as it seems to be in the example?

Comment: What you want is *grouping*, not *sorting*.

Comment: I'm not sure how the keys for the groups are calculated but please take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a complete, working example based on [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

files = ['s1.txt', 'ai1.txt', 's2.txt', 'ai3.txt']

def get_key(fname):
   return int(re.findall(r'\d+', fname)[0])

d = defaultdict(list)
for f in files:
   d[get_key(f)].append(f)

out = [d[k] for k in sorted(d.keys())]
print(out)
```

This produces:

```
[['s1.txt', 'ai1.txt'], ['s2.txt'], ['ai3.txt']]
```

Comment: Really great answer, it worked really well for what I was doing.

Answer (score 4):

```
import itertools
import re

r_number = re.compile("^.*([0-9]+).*$")

def key_for_filename(filename):
    # Edit: This doesn't check for missing numbers.
    return r_number.match(filename).group(1)

grouped = [list(v) for k, v in
           itertools.groupby(sorted(files, key=key_for_filename),
                             key_for_filename)]
```

Comment: +1 I would also put an example key generating function, like `lambda x: re.sub('[^0-9]', '', x)`.

Comment: This answer wrongly assumes that the list is already sorted by number.

Comment: If you make additional assumptions, [you should always mention them](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx).  And in this case, the OP even commented the list is *not* sorted by number.

Answer (score 1):

First, write a function that extracts the number from a file name:

```
def file_number(name):
    return re.search(r"\d+", "s1.txt").group(0)
```

(Note that this function will error out if there's no number at all in the name.)

Sort the list using this function as a key:

```
files.sort(key=file_number)
```

Group by this key using `itertools.groupby()`:

```
for number, group in itertools.groupby(files, file_number):
    # whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work..

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from itertools import groupby
import re
import pprint

def findGroup(record):
    return re.match(".*?(\d+).txt$", record).group(1)

files = [ 's1.txt', 'ai1.txt', 's2.txt', 'ai3.txt', 'foo1.txt', 'foo54.txt' ]

results = {}
for k,g in groupby(files, findGroup):
    if not results.has_key(k):
        results[k] = []
    results[k].append([x for x in g])

pprint.pprint(results)
```

Note, that depending on the order, you'll get lists within lists, but you can collapse those easily enough..

Example output:

```
{'1': [['s1.txt', 'ai1.txt'], ['foo1.txt']],
 '2': [['s2.txt']],
 '3': [['ai3.txt']],
 '54': [['foo54.txt']]}
```