# Fast Population of Key-Value Pair

Tags: python

I am looking for a fast method of creating large key-value pairs that I can simply loop through later on.

```
key = {'a':'stuff', 'a':'more stuff', 'a':'dont look at me', 'b':'test2', 'b':'test3',...'z':'even more stuff'}
for a,b in key
    #do stuff
```

I am looking to condense the reference to `a` into a single statement.

I need `a` in this case to be the key and look through grabbing all the values of `b` that correspond to the current `a`. This is really just readability for later code however if there are other suggestions that can accomplish this task easier that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
key={'a':['stuff','more stuff','even more stuff'],'b':['test2','test3']}
for k in key:
    for val in key[k]:
        #do stuff with values in the key
```

Comment: You know now I just feel stupid.... I saw thinking to myself, no that cant work.... it can't be that simple. FML

Comment: @Blackninja543 if you're doing what I think you're doing, then I had a similar problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466017/sorting-files-in-a-list, `defaultdict` might be of some use to you.

Comment: When I attempt this with a print statement i get the following: `'a':'a'  'b':'b'`

Comment: `for val in k:` will loop over the characters in `k`.  You probably want `for k, vals in key.iteritems():` or `for k in key: for val in key[k]:`, but calling the dictionary `key` is really confusing..

Comment: @DSM Thank you for the suggestion, I fixed it accordingly :)